# node.js eventListener not listen

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm a noob of node.js and i'm following the examples on "Node.js in action".
I've a question about one example : 
The following code implements a simple chat server via telnet. When i write a message, the script should send message to all connected client.

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join',function(id,client){
    this.clients[id] = client;
    this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId,message){
        if(id != senderId){
            this.clients[id].write(message);
        }
    };
    this.on('broadcast',this.subscriptions);
});

var server = net.createServer(function(client){
    var id = client.remoteAddress+':'+client.remotePort;

    client.on('connect',function(){
        channel.emit('join',id,client);
    });

    client.on('data',function(data){
        data = data.toString();
        channel.emit('broadcast',id,data);
    });
});
server.listen(8888);
```

But when i try to connect via telnet and send a message it doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `this.on('broadcast',this.subscriptions);` to do?

Comment: I expected that when someone sent a message, every client connected receive it. But i try to put a console.log inside connect and data events but never arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple issues I noticed. See the comments in the code.

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join',function(id, client) {
    this.clients[id] = client;
    this.subscriptions[id] = function(senderId,message) {
        if(id != senderId)
            this.clients[id].write(message);
    };

    //added [id] to "this.subscriptions"
    //Before you were passing in the object this.subscriptions
    //which is not a function. So that would have actually thrown an exception.
    this.on('broadcast',this.subscriptions[id]);
});

var server = net.createServer(function(client) {
    //This function is called whenever a client connects.
    //So there is no "connect" event on the client object.
    var id = client.remoteAddress+':'+client.remotePort;
    channel.emit('join', id, client);

    client.on('data',function(data) {
        data = data.toString();
        channel.emit('broadcast',id,data);
    });
});
server.listen(8888);
```

Also note: If a client disconnects and another client sends a message then `this.clients[id].write(message);` will throw an exception. This is because, as of now, you're not listening for the disconnect event and removing clients which are no longer connected. So you'll attempt to write to a client which is no longer connected which will throw an exception. I assume you just haven't gotten there yet, but I wanted to mention it.

Comment: Great! The main problem was caused by client.on('connect',function(){}); events. About disconnected user, i have to implement that part yet. Thank you